# selenium how to find element without id

Tags: selenium

I'm currently learning this selenium beginners course. In booking.com based on the tutorial, you can find the id of the element but now that the tutorial was posted several months ago perhaps the web developer made some changes and all I can find now is this line of code and the class="_962ef834c cbe47aa30e" is same as those other filter options too I find that not unique

```
<div data-filters-group="class" class="_962ef834c cbe47aa30e">
```

here's what I did

```
    def apply_star_rating(self):
    star_filtration_box = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'div[data - filters - group = "class"]'
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this css

```
div[data - filters - group = "class"]
```

you have extra spaces with `-`

Please try this CSS :

```
div[data-filters-group='class']
```

or XPath

```
//div[@data-filters-group='class']
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css/xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPath to see if at least the first of the filter fields get highlighted.

```
//*[@div data-filters-group="class"][1]
```

Comment: I'm still in the first couple of hours from the course, I don't know about XPath is still not introduced maybe in later parts of the course thank you for the answer